# How to link a .a/.lib to a .elf

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries, elf

I have a .elf file that is linked to several .a, .so and .lib files. Now I want to add another .lib to the same elf. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Just add the library to your linker commandline.

Comment: Right, but what flags to use? I am using something like this: xyz-link -o final.elf -whole-archive foo.lib bar.elf. This only adds contents of foo.lib to the final.elf and no contents of bar.elf are retained

Comment: You can not use an elf like a library.

Comment: Okay, so can you tell me how to use it in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a .elf file

That statement is meaningless. ELF files come in different varieties: `ET_DYN` (shared library or PIE executable), `ET_EXEC` (an executable), `ET_REL` (relocatable object file), `ET_CORE` (core dump).

You can figure out which kind of `.elf` you have by running `file foo.elf`.

The first two are considered "final", no further linking is possible on them. And obviously you can't relink a `core` file either.

> Now I want to add another .lib to the same elf.

It sounds like you have an executable, which you want to extend.

This is *not possible*.

**Update:**

> can I add .lib to a relocatable object file?

Yes: the same way you add any other libraries. If the original command was:

```
xyz-link -o final.elf -whole-archive foo.lib
```

then the new command would be:

```
xyz-link -o final.elf -whole-archive foo.lib bar.lib
```

Comment: I just checked that it is a shared library. (Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)). I guess further linking is not possible in that case either?

Comment: @AnkurSharma Correct: both `ET_EXEC` and `ET_DYN` are "final".

Comment: can I add .lib to a relocatable object file? If yes, how?